# How to read Headerless file in Selenium DataSource API?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium DataSource API to read excel in my project. I need to read excal as headerless but everytime it taking my first row as header.

Please tell how can i read file excel sheet as headerless file.

Please find Code below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String basePath = "C:\\excel file path";
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.ImportSheet(basePath+"myTestingFile.xlsx");
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table.getHeaderValues().toArray()));

     for(int i = 1 ; i < table.getRowCount();i++){
        table.setRowIndex(i);
       System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0));
    }
  }
```

Please help me out in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version you are using right now. Cause in version 0.7, This issue has been fixed.

Now you can use Excel Sheet as Headerless file.

Find the Code below

```
    String basePath = "C:\\excel file path";
     DataTable table = new DataTable();
     table.setHeaderless();
     table.ImportSheet(basePath+"myTestingFile.xlsx");
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table.getHeaderValues().toArray()));

     for(int i = 1 ; i < table.getRowCount();i++){
        table.setRowIndex(i);
       System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0));
    }
```

Please try with this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to use headerless method of DataTable object. and i tried it with latest version 0.7. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per provided code

> System.out.println(table.getValueAt(0));

here need to use column name like below

```
String name = dt.getValueAt("<-Name of Column->");
System.out.println(name);
```

but used '0' that is the reason why it displaying unexpected results. Please refer doc [here](http://annotation.org.in/Product/SDSProject/documentation.html)